# ios 8 Application Extension to show UIAlertView like view instead of modal UIViewController?

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

I am trying to create the Application Extension with an UIAlertView like view (UIWindowLevelStatusBar Of limited width and height), similar to the way a (UITextView and UIButtons dialog) we share a tweet or post appears from UIActivityViewController

I have added Action Extension from File > New > Target > Application Extension.

[image]

I selected "Presents User Interface". Now, I got ActionViewController and MainInterface.storyboard.
I changed the height (250), tint (red), background (clear color), alpha (0.5) of View Controller in Storyboard. When I run the simulator with Safari, and tap share. I see a extension available there.

And when I press it I see this screen:

[image]

As the Plan B, I selected "No User Interface" from the above image. And tried to access "window" from "appDelegate" to put in its subview. But figure out from here : [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2)

**"Access a sharedApplication object, and so cannot use any of the methods on that object"**

My question is:

Can I show an **Action** App Extension like a UIAlertView and take some input? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrite guys, I found the main issue. In new iOS 8 SDK, you cannot get rid of UIViewController through **Application Extension** so far I have concluded the best bet would be to use **Action Extension**.  If anybody find a good way, please care to share :)